# Mongo shell aggregation query issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am fairly new to MongoDB and I am facing a strange issue.

I've been able to build an aggregation pipeline using a compass.
The query produces the expected result in the GUI but it returns nothing in mongo shell. 
Here is the query :

```
db.searchQueryCollection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        time_stamp: {
            $gte: ISODate("2018-08-13 17:33:20.000"),
            $lt: ISODate("2018-08-13 19:33:20.000")
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$purpose",
        groupedPurpose: {$push: "$purpose"}
    }
}, {$project: {number_of_results: {$size: "$groupedPurpose"}}}])
```

Here is the output in compass : 
[image]

Any idea on what's going wrong?

Comment: use `getCollection("abc")` instead of `searchQueryCollection `

Answer (score 0):

In mongo shell, you should use as below:

```
db.getCollection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME").aggregate([{
    $match: {
        time_stamp: {
            $gte: ISODate("2018-08-13 17:33:20.000"),
            $lt: ISODate("2018-08-13 19:33:20.000")
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$purpose",
        groupedPurpose: {$push: "$purpose"}
    }
}, {$project: {number_of_results: {$size: "$groupedPurpose"}}}])
```

Comment: I got no result either  with `db.getCollection("searchQuery).aggregate(..)` or with `db.searchQueryCollection.aggregate(...)`, but the `.find()` method is working with both syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

If none of your aggregation queries return a result, you may be connected to the wrong database.

If you're connecting using a database driver, check your connection string. In the following example, the database name is at the end of the connection string.

`MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.abcdefg.mongodb.net/databasename`

If you're connecting using MongoDB shell, run the following two commands:

`show dbs;`

```
    admin       288.00 KiB
    config      328.00 KiB
    local        62.66 MiB
    mydatabase    1.24 MiB
```

`use mydatabase;`